# normal Distribution of the Sum of independent Variables \ Using Z table

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, independence, multinomial-distribution

We throw Fake Cube(Containing $1,2,3,4,5,6$) $~300$ times .

Probability of geting $6$ is $\frac{1}{2}$

Probability of geting $1,2,3,4,5~$ is $~0.1$

What is the probability that that the Sum : $~~S \leq 1400$.

**What I tried :**

Let $x_i$ be the number of times we get $i$ in the $300$ throws. ($1 \leq i \leq 6$)

we know that $\sum_1^6 x_i ~~$~ Binomal distribuation

we Shall approximate to **Normal Disturbution**.

so $x^{Normal}_i = \frac{x_i - E(x_i)}{\sigma(x_i)}$ , ie $x_i^{Normal}$~$N~(E(x_i),\sigma^2(x_i))$

OverAll I get that $S$~$~N(300,210)$
but moving to the standard normal Z is large $Z=75.94$

any ideas why ? or even a soultion to this simple problem.

Comment: recall that $E(x_i) = np$ and $\sigma^2(x_i) = npq$

Comment: The sum of binomial distributed variables is binomial distributed when 
1) The variables are independent (which they are not in this case) 
2) they have same parameter p, which is not satisfied either.

Comment: It seems to me that you are only counting the number of times each roll occur, but you are not considering the values of each roll. With your approach it should be
S= 1 x_1 + 2 x_2 + 3 x_3 +...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a variable for each outcome let us denote $S$ as the sum of all the outcomes. That is $S=\sum_{i=1}^{300} X_i$, where $X_i$ is the outcome of one roll.

Since $$E[X_i]= 0.1\cdot(1+2+3+4+5) + 0.5\cdot 6 = 4.5$$
and
$$E[X_i^2] = 0.1\cdot (1+4+9+16+25) + 0.5\cdot 36 = 23.5$$
we have
$$Var(X_i) = 23.5 - 4.5^2 = 3.25$$
Which means that approximately $S \sim N(4.5 \cdot 300 , 3.25 \cdot 300)= N(1350, 975)$, and therefore $P(S\leq 1400)\approx 0.945..$

**EDIT:**
Now suppose that we want to use your approach (which is a slightly more complicated route). The first problem that needs to be addressed is that, if we let $X_i$ denote the amount of times $i$ is observed, then it is true that $X_i \sim Binom(300, p_i)$ where $p_i \in \{ 0.1, 0.5\}$, but it is not true that $X_1,...,X_6$ are independent. We can however use that $(X_1,...,X_6)$ follows a multinomial distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution . Now the sum of $X_i$'s is always 300, but to get $S$ we need to multiply $X_i$ with $i$ yielding that $$S=X_1 + 2X_2 + 3X_3 + 4X_4 + 5X_5 + 6X_6.$$
And therefore
\begin{align*}E[S] = \sum_{i=1}^6 iE[X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^6 i300\cdot p_i = 1350
\end{align*}
Calculating the variance becomes slightly more complicated, since we no longer have independence:
\begin{align*}
Var(S) &= Cov(\sum_{i=1}^6 i X_i , \sum_{j=1}^6 j X_j) \\
       &= \sum_{i=1}^6 \sum_{j=1}^6 i j Cov(X_i, X_j)
\end{align*}
The above sum can be calculated using that $Var(X_i)=300p_i(1-p_i)$ and $Cov(X_i,X_j)=-300p_ip_j$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that and I got it but what’s wrong with the old approach ? I feel like it’s possible too.

Comment: I would love to see the old approach as well because it helps with the understanding not only a final answer

Comment: just to tag ...

Comment: just to be sure did you use the central limit theorem inorder to say that the sum is normal disturbution

Comment: how did you know that they are not independent $x_1 ... x_6$  / why they aren't ?

Comment: Yes the CLT was used. 

Suppose that we roll 300 6's, how many 1's can we then roll ?? The answer is 0. The number of 1's is not independent of the number of 6's. Also, since we have exactly 300 observations, we will always have that $x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_6=300$.

Comment: That’s right ! Thank you very much for clearing things out you really helped a lot !!